# Team Foundation Server 2013 & NUNIT

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, nunit

We currently are using TeamCity as our build server for performing scheduled nightly builds (07:30 & 18:30 using an MSBUILD file we wrote) and also running a suite of NUNIT integration tests.

The company is moving over to TFS 2013 (we use VS2013 PROFESSIONAL) shortly and i was asked if it is possible to import all these projects over to TFS and have it running in the exactly the same fashion as TeamCity has it configured.   My understanding is Yes it should as these are indudstry standard files/projects we have setup and TFS should be well able to accommodate this.

Can anyone absolutely confirm this for me?

Thanks

Comment: [Yes](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0b4dc7dc-822f-4746-8746-6950f52aaa2b/does-tfs2013-build-management-support-nunit-and-nant-?forum=tfsbuild) and [Yes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms253138.aspx) - just from googling your question title. If you really want to know, you could always trial TFS with your code and see if you can get it to work - if you have MSDN it should be easy, otherwise there's VSO or TFS Express

Comment: Thanks Dave, The question was shot @ me with a fairly quick response required so not enough time to trial it in VS just yet.